# Azure custom Login template

Tags: azure

i have created a application which uses Azure login portal to login.

Question 1 ) Can I customize the login screen like Background image or the input field style?

Question 2 ) How can I write a custom HTML so that when we try to open the application It should redirect to my custom designed login screen instead of default Azure login portal UI ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can:

   > Company branding is available only if you upgraded to the Premium or Basic edition of Azure AD, or have an Office 365 license. To learn if a feature is supported by your license type, check the Azure Active Directory pricing information page.
2. You don't have to. If you do Company branding, all login attempts are automatically forwarded to the branded page.

You can find more information here: [Quickstart: Add company branding to your sign-in page in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding)